# Regular expression failed in URL address test

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to build an Regular expression to check valid URL address. for now I tested different address and all was good , but those next (valid) address's failed:

```
    url = "http://example.com/tr/vvf/index.php/docs/po/trf"
   //url = "http://example-a.mydomain.com/test/ny" also not working

    var pattern = new RegExp("(https|ftp|http)://[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?");
    pattern.test(url)
```

I think because of the `index.php/doc...` Any ideas how to fix it

Comment: You need to escape the backslash one more time . Because your pattern is within double quotes and don't forget to use anchors while validating strings.

Comment: i don't think it's a good idea try to come up with a regex yourself matching url. matching url, password, etc should be viewed as an abusement of regex while people keep using it in this way. have a look at https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use regex literal instead of `RegExp` object:

```
var pattern = /(https|ftp|http):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/;
```

`RegExp` works with a string, that requires you to do double escaping so `\w` becomes `\\w` in it.

- [See it working here](http://regex101.com/r/oR8jJ3/2)

Comment: Pattern is not valid (unescaped /), its not anchored so matches *http and `&amp;` ?